How can we understand the timeline of the Tower of Babel?
I'm not finding a coherent explanation of the ENTIRE timing issue of the Tower of Babel. That I'm seeing the issue talked about so little baffles me, as the basic math from a plain reading doesn't seem to work. I have searched for answers and tried to figure it out and am getting nowhere.
This is all in relation to Genesis 11 and 12.
According to the genealogy given in the text, Peleg (named thus "for in his days the earth was divided") was born 101 years after the end of the flood, a descendant of Shem. The Tower of Babel story is inserted in the middle of 2 genealogy listings. All of Noah is before, then Babel, then a further genealogy of Shem, giving father's ages which calculate to the 101 years.
1. How was there a big enough population in 100 years to not only survive, but begin building a city/tower? I have seen calculations and the estimates from both YEC (Young Earth Creationist) and OEC (Old Earth Creationist) sites have calculated a population of around 1,000 people in 100 years, many of whom would be children and ostensibly, half women who wouldn't be much help as they'd be caring for children, food, etc. This is a very generous estimate, by the way, and I'm not sure it accounts for any deaths. This is pushing normal fertility windows pretty hard.
2. The timeline as given makes Noah still alive during the building of the tower. The problem I see here is that as the patriarch and his family were just preserved through the flood, that they would then be part of the building of the tower seems strange. They surely would have taught their families to be obedient.
3. How did they have the technology and means to make fired bricks in only 100 years? Even if they had the knowledge through Noah's family previously, they are starting from scratch after the flood, with only what is on the ark to work with. They would need food, clothing, shelter, etc - and they're building kilns and a city complex already?
4. The text says building the tower was to make a name for themselves. Who were they trying to impress if they were all one family in one area, the flood survivors and their descendants?
I know Torah readers through the years have been able to do basic math - surely even Moses would have known this is not adding up, and yet here it is. There must be an explanation - or at least feasible possibilities - but I can't figure it out. I don't know Hebrew so I'm wondering if there is something lost in translation or perhaps my errant western understanding that is causing the problem. Please help me work through this.

Welcome to MiYodeya Jodi and thanks for these first questions. The guidelines on this site is to ask one question per question. Here you asked many, in case your question gets closed, you are welcome to ask again, one question at a time. Great to have you learn with us!

There are many such issues throughout the Torah, general and specific approaches to handle them have been addressed by R Amnon Bazaq (see his book To this very day and his online classes) as well as R Joshua Berman (see his book Ani Maamin)

I'm sorry. I didn't realize I was to only ask one question at a time. I was trying not to bombard the forum. I have edited my question to explain YEC and OEC and to expand on point #2. Thank you for the book suggestions, also.

Wonderful, thanks

You don't need any specialized technology to make kilns. You can make them from mud bricks.
https://youtu.be/wbc443KVWfI?feature=shared
As for number of people, you only need 70 people to get 70 nations, separated by language. If people had children at age 15, that's 6 generations, stemming from Noah's 3 sons and their wives.  They also lived a long time so they had greater fertile windows to have way more children. The 3 sons would have known what cities are so they wouldn't have to reinvent technology.
As for impressing people, they weren't trying to impress anyone, they were trying to kill God so he couldn't harm humanity any more.

I suppose if they had ovens of a type for cooking, they could have used the same for bricks. Seems like a slow process but we don't know how long they were building before their project was stopped. It does say they were wanting to make a name for themselves in the text I was reading. But I may have a wrong interpretation.
Do you think it is possible the Babel event is not meant to be literal but a lesson? Or that Peleg's 'division' could refer to the dividing of the families into clans/territory?

Orthodoxy holds that things are literally true (unless tradition holds otherwise or there is some blatantly obvious reason why it can't be literally). As for Peleg's division, there is tradition (it's in Rashi) that it refers to the Tower incident but it's not impossible for there to be another reason.

I'm seeing mention of at least one Rabbi (Jose?) saying that Babel was at the end of Peleg's live, not the beginning. That adds a couple hundred more years and helps the timeline, if so. Of course at this point we can't know for sure but that would be possible. I believe he said the name was prophetic. And of course people's names did change at times. Perhaps he had some special unrevealed role in the division to be memorialized in this way. There are so many texts with variations and additional details, it's hard to know which is accurate. Why did they write 'new' stories?
